# Export excel table from server in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, vuejs2, axios

I have problems with exporting tables in javascript. Backend is spring and my method in controller look like this.

```
@PostMapping(produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel")
public void report(@RequestBody @Validated final ReportRequest reportRequest, final HttpServletResponse response, final Principal principal) {
    log.info("'{}' Requested report '{}'", principal.getName(), reportRequest);

    final List<Data> dataList = dataRepository.findAll(
            findByCriteria(
                    reportRequest.getFilterDatas(),
                    reportRequest.getId(),
                    reportRequest.getStartDate(),
                    reportRequest.getEndDate()));

    final SXSSFWorkbook workbook = excelService.generateExcelFromDraData(dataList, FILE_NAME);
    writeToOutputStream(response, workbook);
}
```

On frontend I use vue.js and axios for http client. And export method is:

```
axios.post(
    url+'report',
    query,
    {headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "*",
        "X-XSRF-TOKEN": this.$cookie.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
      }
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";

    var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"});
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'report.xlsx';
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, (error) => {

    }
  )
```

When I hit 'Send and Download' with postman, I get excel that i want. But when i do that from client, I get bytes in response in console.log, but I'cant open excel with message 'excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid...'. If i put report.xls for name, I get excel i can open, but with some bytes that mean nothing.

Any suggestion what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

.xlsx has different [MIME type](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-summary-list/):

> .xlsx:    **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet**

Note that also browsers handle file downloading in different ways. I've used successfully following code (you'll have to change it a bit to use in your app):

```
function successCallback (data) { //In my case data was already a Blob
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { //for IE
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data, 'file.xlsx');
    } else {
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data.slice());
      a.target = '_blank';
      a.download = 'file.xlsx';
      a.dataset.downloadurl = ['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', a.download, a.href].join(':');
      //a.click() got cancelled in firefox 
      var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
      event.initMouseEvent(
              "click",
              true /* bubble */,
              false /* cancelable */,
              window, null,
              0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
              false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
              0 /*left*/, null
              );
      a.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe try setting in `axios.post` config parameter property `responseType: 'blob'` instead of converting it in callback.

Comment: I've done it with putting response type to post request.
`axios.post(
        url+'report',
        query ,
        {headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "*",
            "X-XSRF-TOKEN": this.$cookie.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
          },
          responseType: "arraybuffer",
          }
        ).....`